# Set focus when inserting a hyperlink in wysihtml5 editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysihtml5, bootstrap-wysihtml5

We are using wysihtml5 for a project. We noticed that when editing body text, if you highlight some text, and click the 'Insert link' button in the tool bar that focus is NOT set to the text box in the modal that pops up. The result is, if the user highlights text, clicks the insert link button, and pastes in there url with out first setting focus in the modal, then the url is inserted in the body text (behind the modal).

Looking for ideas in either the css or js on where to try and fix this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded gem from -    bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails (0.3.2.100) to bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails (0.3.3.1) and that fixed the issue for us.